# Why span breaks outside viewport

Tags: html, css

I am trying to work on a time-counter with just basic `CSS` and `JSX/HTML`. I am confused that why the UI breaks when I use `span` as the container. I know it is not a good idea and `div` should be used instead, but I am willing to know the exact reason that is causing this.

P.S. I do understand that it's something to do with `display: inline` as it works fine with `inline-block` as well, but I am not sure what am I missing.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.clock-container {
  background-color: black;
  border: 6px solid rgb(158, 158, 158);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span class="clock-container">
      <span class="time">00</span>
      <span>:</span>
      <span class="time">00</span>
      <span>:</span>
      <span class="time">00</span>
    </span>
```

**Current Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Comment: https://www.samanthaming.com/pictorials/css-inline-vs-inlineblock-vs-block/

Answer (score 0):

Different HTML elements have different default `display` CSS properties, which you can inspect with your browser's developer tools. A `<div>` is equivalent to `<div style="display: block">`. A `<span>` is equivalent to `<span style="display: inline">`. If you were to style your `<span>` with `style="display: block"`, your UI would no longer break.

Further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. I want to know what is causing `display: inline` to break this

Comment: Break what? Be specific. What are you expecting to happen that is not happening?

Comment: @Chinz There is plenty of online documentation regarding the differences between `inline` and `block` and how CSS flows HTML elements. Here's a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flow_layout/Block_and_inline_layout_in_normal_flow